# Stop domains from stealing my scripts NGINX

Tags: nginx

How can I stop some domains from using my files and scripts?

My goal is to stop stealing domains from calling my scripts and execute them.

**I'm on [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/)**

I want to stop these files `(gif|otf|jpg|jpeg|png|css|js)` from being used by `domain1.com`, `domain2.com`, `domain3.com`, etc..

Comment: This is more of a serverfault question, like this https://serverfault.com/questions/907807/how-to-prevent-image-hotlinking-in-nginx

Comment: Find the IP addresses of these offending domains and then apply some ACL rules at `server` level - `deny ip_1; deny ip_2; deny ip_3, allow all;`